# Prevent Vue.js to display brackets on slow clients

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I just made my first `Vue.js` app and it is awesome. The only problem that I have had is related to binding values on slow connections.

For example, in my `template` I have this code:

```
<div v-for="event in events">
    <div class="start_time">
        {{ event.start_time_formatted }}
    </div>
    <div class="icon_placeholder">
        <img v-bind:src="event.icon" alt="Sport Image" />
    </div>
    <div class="event_title">
        <a v-bind:href="event.url">
            {{ event.title }}
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="button_placeholder">
        <a v-bind:href="event.url" class="btn btn-filled">
            Watch
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the problem is that I get this result until all my site's assets are loaded:

[image]

For example, in `AngularJS` example, you can bind values by using directives and prevent the brackets from being displayed.

How can I achieve this effect in `Vue.js`?

Comment: May be it is duplicated, but the answer here is better than all the answers in the other one.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[v-text](http://vuejs.org/api/#v-text) should allow you to render more angular-ish, and and [v-cloak](http://vuejs.org/api/#v-cloak) can help you hide template content until compilation is finished for situations where you need mustache tags.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I'm fetching data from a third party API.

Comment: Where your data is coming from has nothing to do with using v-text, so I don't know what you mean by that.